# is the expression clear? how to compute the 1,2,3 for a point in terms of barycentric coordinates?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

i am asking a question on this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3242302/how-to-compute-the-lambda-1-lambda-2-lambda-3-for-a-point-in-terms-of-bar).

[barycentric coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system) is another coordinates system that is different from Cartesian coordinates system.

[image]

in terms of barycentric coordinates, point B could expressed as (0,0,1)

{1,2,3} is another set of coefficients used to convert a point between the barycentric coordinates and Cartesian coordinates system.

i am concerned about if i express my question clearly by saying

> how to compute the 1,2,3 for a point in terms of barycentric
>   coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to ...

is not a proper questions beginning in English, although everybody will understand the meaning.

You have some alternatives:

> - How can / does one calculate...
> - Which formulas are used to calculate...